# Do things that make noise for more than 20ft get silenced entirely or only within the sphere when done inside of Silence?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I've been thinking about getting Knock anyways because I think thats just a really fun spell for a Bard to have. Like, "Oh we need this door open well allow me! Knock!!!!!!" and it bellows everywhere. But obviously that sound can be detrimental.

Knock can be heard from 300 ft away.

If I cast Silence on the locked item/door prior to casting Knock would the sound be silenced within the sphere but still heard outside of it (dampened) or would that make it not heard at all (muted)?

Comment: You'd at least have to stand outside of the Silence sphere as it prevents Verbal Component Spells such as Knock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silence is pretty clear on the matter.

> no sound can be created within or pass through

Knock doesn't say anything about the spell failing if the noise isn't present. Knock should thus be silent. However, the sound of Knock:

> emanates from the target object

It doesn't emanate from the lock, but from the object targeted (worth noting that Knock includes both a lock and a door as possible objects). If silence is only on one side of a door, Knock will be silent on *that* side of the door, but still be quite loud on the other side! You'll have to encompass the *entire* object you are unlocking to ensure total silence.

Comment: 20'radius sphere area of effect.  I don't think you "other side of the door" is quite right if silence is centered on the lock .  Maybe rethink/revise the answer?