# Can a Sorcerer use the Silence spell and the Subtle Spell Metamagic to silently cast the Knock spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, metamagic

The [*knock*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/knock) spell has a verbal spell component and states:

> [...] When you cast the spell, a loud knock, audible from as far away as 300 feet, emanates from the target object [...]

I'm wondering if you can get around this loud noise by casting the [*silence*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) spell, which states:

> For the duration, **no sound can be created** within or pass through a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on a point you choose within range. Any creature or object entirely inside the sphere is immune to thunder damage, and creatures are deafened while entirely inside it. **Casting a spell that includes a verbal component is impossible there.**

You would ordinarily not be able to cast *knock* as it has a verbal component, but the [Sorcerer's Subtle Spell Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) states:

> When you cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components.

So could a Sorcerer cast *silence* and then a Subtle Spell *knock*? Do these all combine thus letting you cast *knock* without the loud noise being created, or is there some interaction or rule I've overlooked? Does this scenario actually work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## You might not even need Subtle Metamagic

The Knock spell states that:

> [...] When you cast the spell, a loud knock, audible from as far away as 300 feet, emanates **from the target object** [...]

As long as you are outside the Silence when you cast the spell, but the object itself is inside, the Silence spell will absorb the loud noise.

Knock has a 60ft range, so it should be perfectly doable to stand outside the Silence field and cast the spell into it.

Comment: Depending on the goal, this may or may not be enough. Just don't want the loud knock? Perfect! Want to cast knock without being heard? Well, if you're not doing away with the verbal component you'll still have to utter some faux-latin to get the spell effect. Which might ruin a surprise birthday party, a surprise assassination, or any other type of surprise you had planned ;)

Answer (score 16):

## This works

With Subtle Spell, you cast

> without any somatic or verbal components

Thus this casting of the spell is no longer

> a spell that includes a verbal component

Properties of a spell can change for given castings, the main example being its level, depending on the slot. Thus the spell can be cast.

This will also achieve the desired effect, as explained in [this question and answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110370/do-things-that-make-noise-for-more-than-20ft-get-silenced-entirely-or-only-withi?rq=1). Summarized, the sound is not created all over in range, but at the target of *knock*, radiating outwards from it. As that point is within *silence*, the generation of any sound is prevented.